# Reading from a file using JAVA IO in android App

Tags: java, android, file-io, io

I have a file which an external JAR needs. I tried adding that file to assets and provided the path straight away. But that din't work and threw an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/model/en2hi/tune/1/joshua.config: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The line from external JAR trying to read the file is:

```
FileInputStream fis = (filename.equals("-")) ? new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in) : new FileInputStream(filename);
```

Please suggest on how this can to be handled. Is there any other way than keeping that application out of android app? Or how to allow an android app read with Java IO?

Comment: you will need to add that external jar file to your project

Comment: please post the code that attempts to open the file.

Comment: added the line trying to rad file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have you file in **/assets** directory of your project and access it using your AssetManager class:

```
AssetManager aMgr= context.getAssets();
InputStream ipStream = aMgr.open("filename.txt");
```

or you can have it **/res/raw** directory and use it using:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```